# Why we are not using php in Hadoop framework?

Tags: php, hadoop

Any specific reason we are not using php in Hadoop framework?

Comment: erm, they are two completely separate technologies. Nothing stopping you using both?

Comment: only java and python can support Hadoop framework.

Comment: If you know this, why ask such a silly question?

Comment: And anyway, it seems you don't know, here's a guy using PHP with hadoop http://collaboradev.com/2010/12/10/using-hadoop-and-php/

Comment: Look, here's a library you can use https://github.com/dzuelke/HadooPHP

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because he's just plain wrong. Of course PHP can talk to Hadoop

Comment: i need just reason why php mostly not using hadoop framework like java and python. thus why i post a question. thanks your support.

Comment: Hadoop is written in Java by Java developers. As answered, there is little technical limitations to using PHP or other languages with it

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing stopping you from using PHP for Hadoop Streaming MapReduce (assuming PHP can read from standard input and write to standard output).

And there's also not much preventing PHP from being able to query HBase or Hive or Spark Thrift Server assuming a driver exists that allows for that.

The only main issue is that you cannot use the core Java libraries very easily and most services would need exposed via REST, for example.

Any Hadoop web UI could probably be rewritten in PHP, if needed, but it's too much context switching, in my opinion.

A libhdfs C extension does exists, I've not seen it widely used. If you did want to interact directly with HDFS, that's probably the most performant way. Webhdfs would be an alternative

But you'd have to ask the core Hadoop developers why PHP isn't used.